# How to improve question related to editing class files?

Tags: discussion

I often have the problem that I am using a template and there is just small changes I wish to make to the template, such as changing color scheme. However, opening open a .cls file and making changes may often seem to be a challenging task, and especially so for a beginner.

I came across a question recently, which admittedly was not framed properly. I answered the question in a tutorial fashion so that it is beneficial to others as well and so that the author may figure out how to make other changes they may need to.

The question got closed (reasonably so). I have made changes to the question so that it is may be more helpful to others. I feel that we often have this problem about making small changes in the class files and the essence of the question is relevant. How can we improve such a question further?

[Link to the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560487/adjusting-a-resume-on-latex)

Comment: Your answer is very good, (although in future, please don't change UK/US spelling variation (e.g. colour/color, see [American or British English](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7307/2693)). But the real problem with such questions generally is that the tend to be too broad by asking lots of questions at once. So if you have the patience to answer them you should be applauded :) but I don't think they are the kinds of questions that should be encouraged too much.